# Java Script works with a single value but not with two

Tags: javascript, html

I have a Java Script that stops working when I try to input two values. This is the script that works:

```
<HEAD> <script type="text/javascript">
function addsuggest(name)
{
document.getElementById("recipients").innerHTML=document.getElementById("recipients").innerHTML+name+".L ";
}

</script> </HEAD>
<a href=javascript:onClick=addsuggest('3') >click here<a/><br>
<span id=recipients  style="color:blue;"> </span>
```

Nothing fancy. It just adds 3.L in blue color to the end of a line.
I want this function to do some other things so I change `function addsuggest(name)` to `function addsuggest(name, id)` and `onClick=addsuggest('3')` to`onClick=addsuggest('3', 'John')`

These are the symptoms I have:

1. It won't work. I tried making it a button. Again it won't work.
2. When I hover over the link it shows `javascript:onClick=addsuggest('3'` and not the rest. So it's stopped reading it at the comma.
3. Rest of the page content goes blue as if it's link but not clickable.

This is the simplest thing I've done with Java Script. It's just inputting values and then printing it. So, what's the matter?

Comment: What does this have to do with Java?

Comment: @Anthony: `alert('java' != 'javascript'); // true` :P

Comment: No php involved, removing tag

Answer (score 3):

You need quotes surrounding the `href` attribute (and should place them around all other attributes), otherwise the single quotes around the function parameters will break the link:

```
<HEAD> <script type="text/javascript">
function addsuggest(name, id)
{
document.getElementById("recipients").innerHTML=document.getElementById("recipients").innerHTML+name+id+".L ";
}

</script> </HEAD>
<a href="javascript:onClick=addsuggest('3', 'John');" >click here<a/><br>
<span id="recipients"  style="color:blue;"> </span>
```

Comment: Infact, it would be good to put quotes around ALL attribute values, including the id.

Comment: @Endophage - Good point, I've edited my answer to reflect that.

Answer (score 1):

```
<a href="#" onclick="javascript:addsuggest('3');">...</a>
```

and for readability:

```
function addsuggest(name)
{
    document.getElementById("recipients").innerHTML += name + ".L";
}
```